# How to use createRouteFromTrackElement() in Skmap

Tags: android, skmaps

I have some queries regarding the custom route Navigation. I have list coordinates from Source to destination but the first parameter of method is SKTrackElement.
how can we pass that element to methods

Answer (score 2):

[The official documentation](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec012)  tells you how to calculate and display a route out of coordinates

Comment: I want used createRouteFromTrackElement()

Comment: My link points there exactly... See "Calculating routes using a list of points or a GPX file"